# member operator for binary trees

Tags: notation, computer-science

*I want to know if there exists any mathematical operator which can represent the idea of accessing explicitly a member of some object.*

In this case it would be for describing that a node $n_l$ is left child of a node $n$. At the moment I know there exists the operator $::$ which states that its right side operand is member of its left side one. But I want to know if there is some alternative way because in C++ the operator $::$ is used for indicate global scope or static variable accessing.

Here one example: $\text{BalanceFactor}(n)=h(n::n_r)-h(n::n_l)$

Note: I thought in the $\rightarrow$ operator but it is also used in function definitions, I do not want to confuse my students.

Answer (score 0):

The C (and C++, and Pascal, and...) way is to say `struct.member`.

Or use a function: $h(T)$ is the height of the tree $T$. Or use special variables with subindices: $h$ is the height of the tree, $h_l$ is the height of it's left subtree, ...

Just (a) try to be (more or less) consistent in notation, (b) define your usage clearly, and **(c)** use the notation of the textbook/the notation of popular books/sites like Wikipedia, [Wolfram's MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com), perhaps others. Students *will* go looking there, translating to and fro just breeds frustration.